# Фризит ноутбук при подключении к конкретной wifi сети

Tags: windows, сеть, wifi, железо, ноутбук

Столкнулся с очень странной для меня проблемой:
Ноутбук на windows 11 при подключении к публичной сети в отеле, в котором я нахожусь, начинает страшнейше фризить (курсор подвисает на пол секунды-секунду каждые 0.5-2.0 секунды). При отключении, переходе в авиарежим или переподключении на точку доступа с телефона фризы сразу же пропадают.

Что я уже делал и что знаю:

1. Без запущенных тяжелых приложений процесс System расходует около 1% ЦП. Память: 0.1%, диск и интернет не расходует вовсе, но при подключении к этой сети процесс начинает потреблять 15-50% ЦП. Потребление памяти, диска и сети не изменяется.
2. Провел полное сканирование дефолтным дефендером на наличия вирусов. Ничего не обнаружил.
3. Прошерстил все процессы через AnVir Task manager в поисках подозрительных процессов или майнеров, которые могут включаться при подключении к сети, однако, таких не нашел.
4. Обновил все возможные драйвера, включая сетевые.

Конфигурация:

- Computer Type: Acer Aspire A515-44G  (Mobile)
- Operating System: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
- CPU: QuadCore AMD Ryzen 3 4300U, 2328 MHz
- DIMM: (TOTAL 20GB) 16 GB DDR4-3200, 4GB DDR4 SDRAM
- Video Adapter: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics  (512 MB)
- Video Adapter: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics  (512 MB)
- Disk Drive:  WDC PCSN520 SDAPNUW-256G-1014  (256 GB)

Answer (score 0):

Периодически в командировках сталкиваюсь с таким же явлением, если беру корпоративный ноутбук с Windows 11 и использую гостиничную сеть. Причин обычно две:

1. Рутер перегружен, идёт постоянное переподключение
2. Постоянный "перескок" со стандарта на стандарт, например, с `g` на `n` и обратно.

И если со второй проблемой справиться просто - выставляешь принудительно в настройках более низкоскоростной стандарт, то с первой, увы, никак (решение методом геноцида всех остальных постояльцев как-то выглядит непривлекательным :)), - приходится подключаться к телефону.

P.S. На своём ноутбуке с Windows 10 со второй проблемой не сталкивался. Допускаю, это какая-то ошибка в Windows 11.